# Finding the general equation to calculate the number of identical binary symbols out of all possible strings of them.

Tags: combinatorics

I am wondering what is the general formula to calculate the number of ways to combine identical number of binary symbols like 1(s) and 0(s) in random, provided that there are equal number of 1(s) and 0(s)?

For example for n=2, we get all possible combination equals to $2^2=4$ so we have 11, 10, 01, 00. Out of them, we have two (10 and 01) where the number of 1(s)= the number of 0(s).

For n=4, we get 6 and for n=6, we get 20.

What is the general equation?

Answer (score 2):

General expression for an even $n$ is
$$\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}$$
because basically, we have $\binom{n}{n/2}$ ways of choosing the places of $1$'s. And remaining places are automatically for $0$'s. For odd $n$'s, its trivially $0$.